# How do I make a final executable file for my Java program?

Tags: java, deployment, desktop-application

I created a tic-tac-toe game in Java. It runs fine on Eclipse.

How do I compile this file (which is currently a .java file) to the standard file format of Java applications, so it can be run from the desktop like a normal program?

What is the standard file type for the final executable Java application? What should be the file type if I want people to easily and without any computer knowledge run my program on their computers?

Answer (score 5):

with eclipse right click on your project. then export it as a runnable .jar file.

> Project Right Click > Export > Runnable .jar File.

First choose your project under "Launch configuration", then choose your destination.
After that click finish. Your program should be in your destination folder. Double click to start (just like an .exe file)

For example: If you export it to your desktop, and you name it "TicTacToe", the file on your desktop is "TicTacToe.jar" - ".jar" is your executable file

Done

Comment: Does it work if I want to install the file in other computers??

Comment: Yes, you can execute the .jar file on any computer that has java installed.

Answer (score 1):

You have to compile your java class first

```
javac TicTac.java
```

and then execute it

```
java TicTac
```

Note: that here you provide the name of the class with the main method!

Comment: Suppose, you used default package (no package at all). If you used package you have to specify directory to the .java file and then package name for the class you are about to run.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers indicated, you can create an executable jar using eclipse (or a number of other tools).  What these tools are doing under the hood is defining the [Main-Class: attribute](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html) in the jar's manifest.

In Windows, your users can double click on an executable .jar to launch it, as long as the file associations are configured correctly.  However this may not be obvious to windows users who are trained to expect some sort of .exe extension.

To solve this, you could use [launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) to wrap your executable jar in a windows executable.  Note: this doesn't change your java application into a native application (it still requires the JVM, etc), it simply makes it launch more like a native application.

Answer (score 1):

For deploying Java desktop apps., the best option is usually to install the app. using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  JWS works on Windows, OS X & *nix.

Note that JWS is more effort for us to deploy (it involves not only Jarring and signing the code, but creating a JNLP launch file and a page on the net or network to check that Java is installed & serve the files to the user), but is super easy for the end user.

If there is a JWS deployment, the Jar does not have to be an 'executable Jar' as described in the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

The command should be `javac yourFile.java` from you command prompt and then after compilation, class file is created. You can run it using `java MailClassName`
You can find a good [tutorial on using javac and java commands here](http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/07/21/using-javac-and-java-commands-to-compile-and-launch-java-programs/).

Comment: You can't run java file this way

Comment: Thanks. Is this the standard format of java applications? I want my program to be easily runnable on any computer from the desktop, like a normal program.